# Order of subgroup generated by two cyclic subgroups in $S_6$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, abelian-groups

Let $S_6$ be the symmetric group, and $\alpha=(13456)$ and $\beta=(132)$ be its two permutations. How can we find the order of the subgroup generated by $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

SOl: $\alpha^5$=identity permutation and $\beta^3$=identity permutation. How do I use these to list all the members of the subgroup generated using these. I hope there must be some theory behind its solution.

Comment: The initial answer I posted was wrong because $S_6$ is not a commutative group. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The subgroup $G = \langle \alpha,\beta \rangle$ of $S_6$ is clearly transitive and, since $\langle \alpha \rangle$ is transitive on $\{1,3,4,5,6\}$, $G$ is $2$-transitive.

Then $\beta$ of order $3$ stabilizes two points, so $|G|$ is divisible by $6 \times 5 \times 3=90$. Also $G \le A_6$ and $A_6$ has no subgroup of index $2$ or $4$, so we must have $G=A_6$.

If you don't want to use the fact about subgroups of $A_6$, note that $\alpha\beta = (1,4,5,6)(2,3)$, so $(\alpha\beta)^2 = (1,5)(4,6)$ stabilizes $2$ points. Now it is clear that the $2$-point stabilizer is transitive on the remaining $4$ points, so $G$ is $4$-transitive and hence $G=A_6$.